# Viewing backslash code and removing them from a string in Labview 2012

Tags: string, labview, backslash, carriage-return

I'm trying to pass a string to a sub-vi which then does some dynamic data exchange to it but I keep getting a file name error.  I believe this is because there is a carriage return at the end of my string.  When I enable backslash codes I see the carriage return and linefeed codes (/r/n) at the end of my string.  How do I remove these from my string so I can just pass the file name to my sub-vi?  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Trim Whitespace VI. This by default will remove whitespace characters from both front and back of your string.